# NULL in MAX,MIN function in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, bigdata

I need to include `NULL` values while computing `MAX` and `MIN` functions in Hive.  For example, if I have the table:

```
id    values
A     1
B     3
C     NULL
```

then `MAX(values)` should return `NULL`.

Comment: Did this solution work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a flag that says there are `NULL`s in your key-group.  Then you can aggregate that newly created column and look for the presence of your flag, indicating there is at least one `NULL` in the group.

**Data**:

```
key     val
-----------
A       1
A       NULL
B       3  
B       2
C       NULL
C       10
C       4
```

**Query0**:

```
SELECT key
  , CASE WHEN ARRAY_CONTAINS(cs, 1) THEN NULL ELSE m END AS col_max
FROM (
  SELECT key
    , MAX(val) AS m
    , COLLECT_SET(CASE WHEN val IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cs
  FROM database.table
  GROUP BY key ) x;
```

You can also use `SUM()` (or `MAX()`) instead of using `COLLECT_SET()`.

**Query1**:

```
SELECT key
  , CASE WHEN cs > 0 THEN NULL ELSE m END AS col_max
FROM (
  SELECT key
    , MAX(val) AS m
    , SUM(CASE WHEN val IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cs
  FROM database.table
  GROUP BY key ) x;
```

**Output**:

```
key    col_max
--------------
A      NULL 
B      3 
C      NULL
```